# How to solve probability questions?

Tags: probability

Jack and Jill were both sent to the blue room for not completing their probability assignment on time.  When they reported to the blue room, they were each given an envelope with either a green or red card in it.  Jack was told that he can look into Jill's envelope and Jill was told that she can look into Jack's envelope.  Neither of the students was allowed to look into their own envelope and they are not allowed to communicate what they saw in the envelope.  Jack and Jill were then told to guess the colour of their own card and write their guess on their own envelope.  They were informed that both will escape detention as long as at least one of them guess their own colour correctly.  Otherwise, they will serve detention for the rest of the term.

Discuss the probability that Jack and Jill will escape detention.

Comment: Is jack getting a green or red card independent of jill getting a green or red card?

Comment: Did they know this was going to happen before they got into the blue room? (Can they decide on a strategy beforehand?)

Comment: Is it communication if Jill fills out her envelope first, with Jack watching?

Answer (score 2):

With the right strategy, the probability they escape is 1.

Jack should guess that their two colors are the same, and Jill should guess that their two colors are different. Exactly one of them will be correct.

Comment: That seems like it would violate the "no communication" thing. The questions is poorly explained though, so I don't know.